Is this code incorrect, which I found in a C++ book?
As I am reading "Programming: Principles and Practices Using C++" book,
I tried the "The first classic program" as shown in this code:
// This program outputs the message "Hello, World!" to the monitor

import std; // gain access to the C++ standard library 
int main() // C++ programs start by executing the function main 
{ 
  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; // output "Hello, World!" 
  return 0;

}


But when I compiled this code in vs code it returns a confusing error to me and I wonder why it isn't valid.
What do you think?
I tried implementing this code in vs code, but I got this error:
Cpp.cpp:1:1: error: 'import' does not name a type
 import std;
 ^~~~~~
Cpp.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Cpp.cpp:4:9: error: 'cout' is not a member of 'std'
         std::cout<<"Hello,World\n";
         ^~~


The code is correct C++20, but you are using C++11.

The code is correct in the latest version of C++. Specifically if you use C++20. Your compiler must be defaulting to an earlier version of C++.

To make the code work in C++11 replace import std; with #include <iostream>

This is c++20, not c++11. What was the error message? import is new to c++ and requires modules, which I'm not sure if it's fully supported in msvc yet, but if so you'll need to make sure you've set it to use the c++20 compiler.

The good news is you seem to have an up-to-date book, but not an up-to-date compiler yet

I won't close-vote for typo. One of the other commenters (or you yourself, Souhil) please create an answer.

@john is right about how to make this work with c++ 11. But seeing which book you use, I think the right thing to do is to use/coinfigure a corresponding compiler. You might need help/tutorials to setup vs code accordingly, it is not beginner-friendly.

I am using vsc and i don't which c++ version i am using! lets pretend that its the latest version i am using.. i tried to copy this code from a book and paste it in my vsc but the terminal shows an error as shown in the second block.

You must first learn how to configure your platform. It's not part of the standard, thus not covered in a general book on C++. For MSVS, you need the latest IDE update installed and /std:c++20 switch or higher (c++2a). The default standard setup is not suitable. You must also read the doc on MSVS project properties.

@3CxEZiVlQ • import std; is C++23, P2465R3.

In the book, did you read the part that says: What if you don’t have an up-to-date C++ implementation that supports module std?

I am using vsc and i don't which c++ version i am using! What OS are you using? What compiler did you install? With that said I don't know of a compiler that defaults to c++23. Microsoft's compiler msvc defaults to c++14. I believe g++ has different defaults depending in the version however none of them are c++23. clang++ on macOS defaults to the 1998 standard! If you are on windows and using  VSCode make sure that you followed the VSCode instructions and installed msys2 to install your compiler. The default would install a compiler that is 6+ years old.
